# Uploading remote image to webpage using Chrome File Upload Dialog

Tags: google-chrome, image-uploading, image-upload

How do I upload an image that is located on the web to a different webpage without manually downloading and uploading it?

**Example**: Using the Chrome browser I want to upload the Wikipedia logo onto this post. I copy the URL of the image, https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png, and on this page I click *Image* and paste the URL in the Upload File Dialog but then I get an error.

Screenshot of error at Chrome's Open File Dialog:

[image]

I used to be able to just paste the URL of a remote image and it would upload it as if it was a local file (probably downloading it to the Windows temporary internet files folder).
I'm not sure what happened, but when I try this now I get an error stating that the *"The RPC has failed and did not execute"* (translated from Dutch). Searching the internet for this error related to Chrome uploads gave no results.

Is my computer being weird, or have I been using a functionality that shouldn't have worked in first place?

Comment: I upload remote files the same way and it works for me on Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit) and Windows 10.0.14393.

Comment: Strange, that would suggest something in my computer is borked, any idea on what I should look into?